# How to take a full resolution picture with camera in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to take a full resolution picture with nativescript camera module ... but i can't !

I know how to do that with cordova but not in nativescript :-( and all examples are with small res like 300x300.

```
const options = {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    keepAspectRatio: false,
    saveToGallery: true
};
```

I'm looking for something like "0x0" or no width and height options but if i try to put 4096x3072 (my camera resolution) the result is "out of memory".

Thanks

Comment: The plugin returns image asset, while on Android you can simply call `asset.android` for the actual image's path which will be high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use nativescript media file picker  https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-mediafilepicker Or nativescript camera plus https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nstudio%2Fnativescript-camera-plus  for full screen camera.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply but nativescript-camera-plus demo does'nt work ... tons of errors when i try to launch demo-ng (look at https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus/issues)
And i don't know how to take a full res picture with "nativescript media file picker" ...